# Inserting into a joined view SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

This is a question more about design than about solving a problem.

I created three tables as such

```
CREATE TABLE [CapInvUser](
    [UserId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [AreaId] [int] NULL,
    [Account] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [mail] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [UserLevelId] [int] NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [CapInvUserLevel](
    [UserLevelId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Level] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [CapInvUserRegistry](
    [UserRegistryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserLevelId] int NOT NULL,
    [DateRegistry] DATE NOT NULL,
    [RegistryStatus] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

)
```

With a view that shows all the data on the first table with "AreaId" being parsed as the varchar identifier of that table, the UserLevel being parsed as the varchar value of that table, and a join of the registry status of the last one.

Right now when I want to register a new user, I insert into all three tables using separate queries, but I feel like I should have a way to insert into all of them at the same time.

I thought about using a stored procedure to insert, but I still don't know if that would be apropiate.
 My question is

- **"Is there a more apropiate way of doing this?"**
- **"Is there a way to create a view that will let me insert over it? (without passing the int value manually)"**

--This are just representations of the tables, not the real ones.
-- I'm still learning how to work with SQL Server properly.

Thank you for your answers and/or guidance.

Comment: `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` on view?

Comment: I'm thinking that INSTEAD OF might be the answer to this. But I'm not sure if it's better than using a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way of doing this, in my experience, is to write a stored procedure that does all three inserts in the necessary order to create the FK relationships.

This would be my unequivocal recommendation.